# Retrieve contents of a tag using XPath in Google Sheets, but *not* the contents of nested/child tags

Tags: google-sheets, xhtml

I'm trying to retrieve one portion of a `<h1>` tag using the Google Sheets IMPORTXML function. The funtion below gets everything within the `<h1>`, but I only want the text starting at Lenovo..... and ending at Silver. I do not want the Item #... that is in the nested `<span>`.

Is there a way to get the `<h1>`, but ignore the nexted span?

**Working Function**

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.officedepot.com/a/products/"&A2,"//div[@id='skuHeading']/h1[@class='semi_bold fn']")
```

**Structure**

```
<div id="skuHeading" data-auid="productDetail_text_skuDescription">
    <h1 itemprop="name" class="semi_bold fn">
        Office Depot&reg; Brand White Copy Paper, Letter Paper Size, 20 Lb, 500 Sheets Per Ream, Case Of 10 Reams
        <small class="item_sku" data-auid="productDetail_text_sku">
        <span itemprop="sku"> 
            Item&nbsp;# 273646
        </span>
    </small>
    </h1>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Post your structure as text, not as a screenshot.

Comment: @Alohci, thanks for taking a look. I've updated the question with a text version of the structure.

Comment: FYI, this worked as well `/h1[@itemprop='name']/node()[count(text()) = 0]`  |'-'|, do you want to post the answer so I can award you the points?